# Redirect output from -exec in find command to variable

Tags: shell, find, ksh

I have a command in the form:

```
find -name *.* -type f -exec rm {} -v \;
```

And I want to get the list of files that it processed into a variable. How would I do that in ksh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 VAR=`find /dir -name '*.*' -type f -print -exec rm {} \;`
```

Comment: Use `$()` in lieu of backticks as the latter has been deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Append a "-print" after your arguments

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
VAR=$(your statement)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a ksh-user, so I might be wrong. In bash, I have to mask the asteriks:

```
find -name "*.*" -type f -exec rm {} -v \;
```

and I can use -delete instead of -exec rm, but delete is special for GNU-find:

```
find -name "*.*" -type f -delete
```

and to output the file names, append a print:

```
find -name "*.*" -type f -delete -print
```

and capture the output

```
deleted=$(find -name "*.*" -type f -delete -print)
```